# Flush cache after multithreaded mapping writes to primitive arrays

Tags: java, multithreading, visibility

This question relates to the latest version of Java.

I have a primitive two-dimensional array sized as below.

```
int[][] array = new int[numPasses][n*10]; //n threads write; during the i-th pass, the k-th thread writes to array[i] at locations k*10 to (k+1)*10-1.
//the array above is allocated at the beginning, and constantly rewritten.
```

During  pass `i`, each of `n` producer threads writes to its own memory location in `array[i]`, so there are no race conditions during the write process. After writing, `m` consumer threads read the results of this write. I do not need the consumers to access `array[i]` at any point in time before all the writes are done.

**My first question:** Would a structure like the following flush all the producer writes from cache? If not, how would one go about doing this for primitive arrays? (For technical reasons, I cannot use Atomic*Arrays.)

```
void flush() {//invoked after writes from all producer threads are done.

  if(producerThreadID == 0) {
  synchronized(array[i]) {//done at pass i.

  }
}
```

**My second question:** Is there a better way to do this?

**EDIT:** Okay, I accept that what I want to do is essentially impossible with the empty synchronized block. Let's say that, instead of the structure above, each producer thread has access to its own pass, i.e.:

```
int[][] array = new int[numPasses][n*10]; //n = numPasses threads write; during the i-th pass, the i-th thread writes to all elements in array[i].
```

(This is Zim-Zam's suggestion.)

**My (hopefully final) question:** Then, would the following structure in the i-th thread ensure visibility for consumer threads after the `synchronized` block?

```
//i-th producer thread acquires lock on array[i]
 void produce() {
   synchronized(array[i])

       //modify array[i][*] here
   }
```

Comment: If you can use JNI, you can use intrinsics to write with non-temporal hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm is probably going to create [false sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing), which occurs when two threads write to nearby memory locations - if thread1 and thread2 are writing to data that shares a cache line, then the cache protocol will force thread2 to block until or re-execute after thread1 completes or vice versa.  You can avoid this by using coarser grained parallelism, e.g. use one thread per pass (one thread per array) rather than one thread per array element - this way each thread is operating on its own array and there probably isn't going to be any false sharing.

Comment: Unfortunately, for other technical reasons, I cannot have each thread write to its own array. But I repeat: will the empty synchronized block do what I expect it to?

Comment: @user2650947 No, `synchronized` blocks will flush variables modified within the block when the block exits - they won't flush the contents of the block's monitor.  You would need to have each thread make its array modifications from within a `synchronized` block in order to do what you're trying to accomplish.  Due to the problems of false sharing and synchronization overhead, it would probably be more efficient to use a single thread to update the arrays.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I will have to have each thread write to its own array. Please let me know if my modified approach (edited above) will work.

Answer (score 0):

I would study carefully your reasons or not using `Atomics` because they are exactly what you are needing.

If there is truly a problem then have you considered using `sun.misc.Unsafe` like the `Atomics` [use](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.java)?

Alternatively - use an array of objects holding a `volatile` field.

```
class Vint {
  public volatile int i;
}
Vint[] arr = new Vint[10];

{
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = new Vint();
  }
}
```